# Sequelize ORM is not retrieving all records as expected, while raw queries work correctly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, join, orm, include

Sequelize ORM is not retrieving all records as expected, while raw queries work correctly. sequalize orm not retrieving  last table's data. but all records are coming in raw query and in pgsql
This is my code

```
const result = await CDMGoal.findAll({
    attributes: [

        'name',
    ],
    include: [{
        model: ActorGoals,
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [{
            model: ActorRole,
            attributes: [
                ['id', 'actor_id'],
                ['name', 'actor_name']
            ],
            include: [{
                model: CdmProvicerActorRole,
                attributes: ['id'],
                include: [{
                    model: CdmProvider,
                    attributes: ['name'],
                }, ],

            }, ],
            where: {
                id: {
                    [Op.in]: [3, 4]
                }
            },
        }, ],
    }, ],
    where: {
        id: [34, 35],
    },
}, {
    // logging: true
    // raw: true, // Set to true to get plain JSON objects instead of Sequelize instances
});
```

i want all table's data